# signing message

Tags: wallet, signature

I'm trying to sign a message with the Bitcoin Core version v0.19.0.1 wallet.  But when I do I see the message "the entered address does not refer to a key."  is there a way to sign a message with the addresses in this wallet?  Thx for any help.

Comment: Is that a watch-only address?

Comment: It originally held my btc but I moved them to a new address, so the wallet is actually empty.  I'm just trying to sign a message with one of the now empty receive addresses to verify I control it.

Comment: Shouldn't matter if an address is "empty" -- is it a bech32 (native segwit) address? There is a proposal for message signing with such an address but I don't think any code is merged yet: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0322.mediawiki

Comment: I actually imported the private keys into electrum and was able to sign a  message.